# Adding MSO Gallery command to custom PowerPoint Ribbon

Tags: xml, vba, ribbon, powerpoint

I made a custom ribbon in PowerPoint for our staff. Most of the commands on the ribbon link to custom built VBA scripts but I would like to include one standard MSO Gallery command (`MSO:SlideNewGallery`).

I have successfully added the button to the ribbon. Looks nice but does not work. I don't know how to call the action to a standard MSO gallery command. I tried writing a VBA script but the gallery commands don't work well in VBA so the Script just creates a new slide and does not show the `SlideNewGallery` options.

I am self-taught and I think I am probably just missing something very simple.

My questions:

- What should I do?
- Should I do this in VBA or in XML?

Here is my ribbon xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="RibbonControl.Onload">
        <ribbon>
            <tabs>
                <tab id="CustomTab1" label="Insurance">
                    <group id="CustGrp1" label="Template" >
                        <button id="Btn1" label="New Presentation" screentip="Create a new presentation" image="Default" size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
                    </group>
                    <group id="CustGrp20" label="Insurance Resources" >
                        <gallery id="SlideNewGallery" label="New Slide" screentip="Insert an new slide" imageMso="SlideNewGallery"  size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
                        <button id="Btn22" label="Insert Herman" screentip="Insert a Herman Picture" image="HermanIcon"  size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
                        <button id="Btn23" label="Insert Logo" screentip="Insert a logo for OMA Insurance or any of our affilliates" image="OMAInsurance"  size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
                        <button id="Btn21" label="Content Ideas" screentip="See or copy our favourite insurance presentations" imageMso="BuildingBlockProperties" size="large" 
                        onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
                        <button id="Btn24" label="Insurance Brand Standards" screentip="Go to the Insurance Brand Standards Document" image="Brand"  size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
                    </group>
                    <group id="CustGrp3" label="Tools" >
                        <button id="Btn30" label="Convert to Brand" screentip="Convert this Presentation to BRAND style" image="Convert" size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
                        <button id="Btn31" label="Reset Slide" screentip="Apply the fonts and layouts of our Brand" imageMso="QuickStepsGallery" size="large" 
                        onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
                        <button id="Btn32" label="Insert Asterisk" screentip="Insert an Asterisk" image="AsteriskIcon"  size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
                        <button id="Btn33" label="Select Everything" screentip="Select all the text in the active area" imageMso="LassoSelect" size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
                    </group>
                </tab>
            </tabs>
        </ribbon>
    </customUI>
```

Comment: should it possibly be `<gallery idMso="SlideNewGallery"...`?  (Just a hunch) also, if you have a subroutine attached to the `onAction`, please show the code for that macro.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help, I eventually got everything to work by putting mso: in front of every element.

I am not really sure why this worked... but everything is good now. Below is the working code.

```
<mso:customUI xmlns:mso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui"><mso:ribbon><mso:tabs><mso:tab id="CustomTab1" label="Insurance">

<mso:group id="CustGrp1" label="Template" ><mso:button id="Btn1" label="New Presentation" screentip="Create a new presentation" image="Default" size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" /><mso:gallery idQ="mso:SlideNewGallery" size="large" showInRibbon="false" visible="true"/>
</mso:group>

<mso:group id="CustGrp2" label="Insurance Resources" >
<mso:button id="Btn22" label="Insert Herman" screentip="Insert a Herman Picture" image="HermanIcon"  size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
<mso:button id="Btn23" label="Insert Logo" screentip="Insert a logo for OMA Insurance or any of our affilliates" image="OMAInsurance"  size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
<mso:button id="Btn21" label="Content Ideas" screentip="See or copy our favourite insurance presentations" imageMso="BuildingBlockProperties" size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
<mso:button id="Btn24" label="Insurance Brand Standards" screentip="Go to the Insurance Brand Standards Document" image="Brand"  size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
</mso:group>


<mso:group id="CustGrp3" label="Tools" >
<mso:button id="Btn30" label="Convert to Brand" screentip="Convert this Presentation to BRAND style" image="Convert" size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
<mso:button id="Btn31" label="Reset Slide" screentip="Apply the fonts and layouts of our Brand" imageMso="QuickStepsGallery" size="large"  onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
<mso:button id="Btn32" label="Insert Asterisk" screentip="Insert an Asterisk" image="AsteriskIcon"  size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
<mso:button id="Btn33" label="Select Everything" screentip="Select all the text in the active area" imageMso="LassoSelect" size="large" onAction="RibbonControl.MyBtnMacro" />
</mso:group>

</mso:tab></mso:tabs></mso:ribbon></mso:customUI>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
          <control idMso="SlideNewGallery"
               size="large"/>
```

If you use gallery the thumbnails may not update properly